# Miller-Rabin primality test-SAGE

Tags: sage, primality-test

I'm trying to program the Miller-Rabin primality test in SAGE. Here is my code:

```
def miller(n,k):
i=1
s=(n-1).valuation(2)
t=(n-1)/(2**s)
while(i>0 and i<=k):
    a=randint(3,n-3)
    if gcd(a,n)!=1:
        i=0
    else:
        y=a**t%n
        if y!=1 and y!=n-1:
            j=1
            while(j>0 and j<=s-1 and y!=n-1):
                y=y**2%n
                if y==1:
                    j=0
                else:
                    j=j+1
            if y!=n-1:
                i=0
        if i>0:
            i=i+1
if i==0:
    print "n composite"
else:
    print "n probably prime"
```

It works fine for not-too small numbers, however for n=3847982374893247238947238473289472348923784923748723482374832748923748932478239472389478239479273 I get "exponent must be at most 9223372036854775807". I would apreciate any advice :)

Comment: You might want to replace a pattern `x^y%z` with a pattern like `mod(x,z)^y`, so you do the exponentiation **after** the modular reduction (i.e. much smaller values).

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the issue.  Simply replacing with `y=mod(a,n)^t` yielded `n probably prime`: see [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUu1ugyAU_d-k78CaLAGnm4IJupQ9yhLa4oZDNOq2-PbjQ1vruD_IzT3nXM4JXEQFGqmU6KGOv9DrfgdMSZb5ZmBQJxl6_uHqm4-y1RAjj4weeYE4ioZ59vsplYDyLQVcX4A8sutCW5z1Ziz1CEmsE4JuiKzAx_kCeazRA8tWEu8lvQ2EGsQGn1jTeu37uFFWYDL7nBnTGLsbqa16ibouH6Seg9RHNiTrNSiwx1uZogg_6jBq7bB_8e69pGEwEPteVz8FUvj84dgO315nBObxAmzJ5HKB5TC2JnW9eVNw0ODcNl07yFEcPLhxfeV1fXviJzXZSbOQbe1381ckRU7LAhOaFyXBOcWkKN2ZU4J9axCDF3npWG7gOoKph2apmZbLAt-XmJIYp-gPP8iagw==&lang=sage).